# Pydantic can't validate the nested model

Tags: python, pydantic

I expect to get the response as as a list, e.g.:

```
{orders: [{'id': 111, 'info': {'dt': '2023-05-11'}}, ...]}
```

Schemas:

```
class OrderInfo(BaseModel):
    dt: date

class Order(BaseModel):
    id: int
    info: OrderInfo

class Orders(BaseModel):
    orders: List[Order]
```

Here I iterate over the data to append the list:

```
@app.get("/", response_model=Orders)
async def get_orders():
    orders = []

    for i in data:
        order = Order.parse_obj(i)
        orders.append(order)

    return Orders(orders=orders)
```

Here data is a list of dicts:

```
[
{'id': 111, 'dt': '2022-01-13', 'quantity': 5},
{'id': 112, 'dt': '2022-01-14', 'quantity': 10}
]
```

Looks like pydantic can't resolve the nested model OrderInfo:

```
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for Order
info
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
```

If I declare the OrderInfo as nullable, then I can get the results, but with nulls:

```
{"orders": [{"id":111,"info":null}, ...}
```

Comment: What does your input data look like? Where is the `data` variable coming from? Please update this question so that it includes a [mcve].

Comment: I don't understand why you expect to be able to parse a dictionary like `{'id': 111, 'dt': '2022-01-13', 'quantity': 5}` as an `Order` instance. You defined a non-optional `info` field on `Order`, yet no such key is present in the dictionary. That is what the error is telling you. What did you expect? If you want the `Order` model to be able to take the `dt` value instead and construct an `OrderInfo` from that automatically, you need to write a custom validator for that. Is that your goal?

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg, yes, this is exactly what I need. There is one example with nested models I found: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body-nested-models/#nested-models. Could you please share an example how to achieve this with the custom validator ? Thank you!

Comment: @Alex Will do, as soon as the question is reopened. Meanwhile, take a closer look at that FastAPI example you shared. There the nested data _matches_ the model schema: The `Item` model has an `image` field with the `Image` type **and** the expected request body has an `image` key with the corresponding nested object having the keys that match the `Image` schema. Therefore no custom validation/manipulation is needed. Pydantic can automatically parse the nested model because the data matches the schema. (Unlike in your case here.)

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg I think someone else needs to vote to reopen this question.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg I posted the new question here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76172012/how-to-reshape-the-data-using-nested-models-with-pydantic
Could you please take a look. Thank you!

Comment: Alright, you may want to delete this question then.