# How to reshape the data using nested models with Pydantic

Tags: python, pydantic

I expect to get the response as as a list, e.g.:

```
{orders: [{'id': 111, 'info': {'dt': '2023-05-11'}}, ...]}
```

However the input data here is a list of flat dicts:

```
data = [
{'id': 111, 'dt': '2022-01-13', 'quantity': 5},
{'id': 112, 'dt': '2022-01-14', 'quantity': 10}
]
```

Schemas:

```
class OrderInfo(BaseModel):
    dt: date

class Order(BaseModel):
    id: int
    info: OrderInfo

class Orders(BaseModel):
    orders: List[Order]
```

Here I iterate over the data to append the list data:

```
@app.get("/", response_model=Orders)
async def get_orders():
    orders = []

    for i in data:
        order = Order.parse_obj(i)
        orders.append(order)

    return Orders(orders=orders)
```

In my case the input data is a flat json (see below), which pydantic can't resolve into the nested model OrderInfo:

```
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for Order
info
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
```

If I declare the OrderInfo as nullable, then I can get the results, but with nulls:

```
{"orders": [{"id":111,"info":null}, ...}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to allow for your input data to have some fields missing, but those fields to be automatically constructed from data in other fields, you would usually use a custom [root validator](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/validators/#root-validators).

However, you need to remember that root validators are called *after* the field validators (as mentioned in the linked docs section). This means, if the missing fields are non-optional, a validation error will be picked up before the root validator is even called.

In that case you will need to make it a `pre=True` root validator, so that it is called *before* the regular field validators.

Here is how you could do it:

```py
from datetime import date

from pydantic import BaseModel, root_validator


class OrderInfo(BaseModel):
    dt: date


class Order(BaseModel):
    id: int
    info: OrderInfo

    @root_validator(pre=True)
    def info_from_dt(cls, values: dict[str, object]) -> dict[str, object]:
        if "info" in values or "dt" not in values:
            return values
        values["info"] = {"dt": values["dt"]}
        return values
```

If the `info` field is present, then we should assume all is fine and there is no need to customize anything.

Similarly, if `dt` is missing, there is no way to construct the `info` data anyway, so we can just allow the default validators to take over.

But if `info` is missing and `dt` is present, we can construct the `info` ourselves.

Here is a little demo:

```py
order_data = {"id": 111, "dt": "2022-01-13", "quantity": 5}
order = Order.parse_obj(order_data)
print(order)
```

Output: `id=111 info=OrderInfo(dt=datetime.date(2022, 1, 13))`

Comment: Thank you, @Daniil Fajnberg! Is my understanding correct, in this case since I am using the `root_validator`, I don't really need to define another class `OrderInfo`?

Comment: No... This solution rests on the assumption that you _do_ have an `OrderInfo` model and the `info` field of `Order` is of that type, but that your input data does not correspond to this schema, because it is missing the `info` key. Whether or not you want the schema to be that way or not is up to you. I just gave you a solution based on the premises _you_ gave.